# Async load CommonJS modules in SystemJS static bundle

Tags: javascript, systemjs, jspm

I'm trying to create a static build with jspm/SystemJS.

```
var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');

var builder = new Builder('/', 'config.js');

builder.buildStatic('main.js', 'main.bundle.js', {
    config: {
        format: 'cjs'
    }
});
```

Inside of this static build, I want to be able to asynchronously load dependencies using `System.import()` calls (which transpile to `System["import"]('my/file/path.js')` in the bundle).

When I try and load these dependencies, after a click event, for example, I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

This error *only* occurs after the click event, which leads me to believe that the bundled file includes the `system-register-only` version of `system.js`.

**How can I either include the full `system.js` in my single-file bundle or convert this `System.import()` calls to a format that would allow me to fetch JavaScript modules asynchronously?**